# Java Swing Menu Beginners Advice

Tags: java, swing, menu, actionlistener

I just started studying some java GUI techniques and I have created a small program which has a menu bar a menu as well as an item within that menu. Now what I want to do is to implement a file chooser so when the item in the menu is selected then the file chooser is executed. The problem is that the file chooser that I created is in another class. Is there any possible way to start my file chooser's class when the item in the menu is clicked?
Here is my code

```
  public class menu {


  public static void main(String[] args){


//to menu
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(600,400);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
JMenu search = new JMenu("Browse");
bar.add(search);
final JMenuItem songstoplay = new JMenuItem("Browse Songs To Play");
search.add(songstoplay);



//to outline
  final Container content = frame.getContentPane();
   content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
   JLabel text = new JLabel("My first iteration", JLabel.CENTER);
   text.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
   text.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
   content.add(text);


 JLabel text2 = new JLabel();


 text2.setText("List of drives connected: C:/");
 text2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
  text2.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
 content.add(text2);


}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling file choosers constructor ?

Comment: why don't you try [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)?

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. But this is what I am asking how to use the filechooser one the menu item is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the JFileChooser, you have to add an eventlistener on your menuitem. Better you take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

or the direct link to the code from the example above:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java

Comment: Hey thanks for your advice i resolved the problem that i had by adding an actionlistener :D